# spring jpa onetomany join table auditing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I have a oneToMany and ManyToOne mapping in my models:

class college

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "collegecource", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "college", referencedColumnName = "college"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cource", referencedColumnName = "cource"))
private Set<course> course;
```

In a relation able table collegecource i have one extra column isActive

I want to audit all the tables with create/update/delete.

I added @Audited in collegecource

```
@Audited
public class collegecource
```

When i try to create/update parent with relational data Audit working fine.
But when i try to delete relational data (Child data) it is not auditing.

Can You please help me.

Comment: do you have @Audited in Cource?

Comment: So your problem is when you remove `collegecource` from a `college`, not audit operation occurs for neither `collegecource` nor `college`?  I assume `college` is also annotated with `@Audited`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want audit field, Annotation your field with @Audited.

> (Child data)